# What is the state of the art on Quantum Random Access Memories?

Tags: ibm-q-experience, experimental-realization, architecture, research, quantum-memory

I realized that Quantum Random Access Memory (qRAM) was proposed to make quantum computers more similar to classical one. Currently quantum computers have very constrained memory, given only quantum registers on quantum processors can be used for an algorithm to run. It is true that e.g. Qiskit language allows to use RAM or HDD of classical computer, however, resulting algorithms are hybrid quantum-classical.

I found some proposals how to implement qRAM, e.g. [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/0708.1879).

But my understanding is that the device is highly experimental nowadays.

**So my questions are those:**

1. Does anybody know about progress in this field? Some links to articles of state-of-art implementation of qRAM will be highly appreciated.
2. What about IBM Q? Do we have an opportunity to use qRAM on IBM Q computer in foreseeable future (i.e. few years)?

Comment: last time I checked, no experimental implementation of the qRAM protocol as originally proposed by Giovannetti et al. exists. The technology is just not there yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to comment provided by user *gIS*, there was no progress in implementing qRAM as proposed in [the paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/0708.1879).

However, some additional information on qRAM physical implementation can be found on this forum [here](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/1195/state-of-the-art-in-quantum-memory?rq=1).