# Finding minimum with Grover

Tags: quantum-algorithms, programming, grovers-algorithm

I am a beginner in quantum computing. I have already computed the sat quantum solver with Grover search and then, I would like to compute the "minimum search" of Dür and Hoyer. My question is: Is it possible to encode a list with two registers of qubits?

If it is possible, I would like to see a general methods with explanations of how to encode a list in a quantum circuit. :)

Ref: [A Quantum Algorithm for Finding the Minimum](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9607014)

Comment: Hi and welcome to Quatum computing SE. I am afraid that currently the minimisation algorithm you linked is impossible to implement on current quantum computer as they do not have RAM memory (qRAM) which could contain the table with function values. See discussion on qRAM here https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/9413/what-is-the-state-of-the-art-on-quantum-random-access-memories.

Comment: Here https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/9507/travelling-salesman-problem-on-quantum-computer/ you can see discussion on another algorithm using the minimization. As you can see, the minimization is only discussed however practical implementation is not provided.

Comment: thank you! but if I want to « test » this algorithm, is it possible to simulate the QRAM ? And create an index state entangled with T[i] state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [article](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1502.04943.pdf) purpose a method to encode a list in quantum circuit.

An example for the list : [1, 3, 0, 2] and the Grover search, where is 0 ? 
[image: Grover search]

And the result : index 2
[image: Result]