# How to code the "minimum search" algoirithm of Dürr and Hoyer with Grover's search?

Tags: quantum-algorithms

I am a beginner in quantum computing. I have already computed the SAT quantum solver with Grover search and then, I would like to compute the "minimum search" of Dürr and Hoyer. I am not getting how to code this algorithm. Can someone please share the coded program?

Comment: Hello, welcome to the quantum computing stack exchange, could you be a bit more precise on the algorithm or provide a link were we can find more ? Could it be [this one](https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/9607014.pdf) ? Could this [question](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/11409/finding-minimum-with-grover?rq=1) help ?