# QML: "Quantum Data loader" instead of QRAM?

Tags: quantum-algorithms, machine-learning

In last year‘s conference "Quantum For Business 2019" Iordanis Kerenidis gave [a nice talk about quantum machine learning](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UZ9VukrhLg8&list=PLh7C25oO7PW1_kAAhy85diTKGaYlXNtwV&index=7).

At about time 27:10 he mentions a "Quantum Data loader" as an alternativ for QRAM. To me it sounds very concrete but I can not find any reference for it. Has somebody any details about it or did I get this wrong?
I have looked at arxiv papers 1911.01117 and 1812.03584, that he probably referred to in his talk. But these seem to use QRAM explicitely.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Quantum Computing SE. Something on qRAM which may be useful: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/9413/what-is-the-state-of-the-art-on-quantum-random-access-memories

Comment: thank you for the link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He generally refers to QRAM. But there are other ways to load data in a quantum computer, generally referred as quantum embeddings or quantum feature maps. They are generally more near-term oriented than QRAM. Yet with a QRAM, you can design an algorithm with the goal of obtaining a possible expression of a speedup against a classical version.
This [article](https://arxiv.org/abs/1804.11326), and this [one](https://arxiv.org/abs/2001.03622) are examples/references you can learn about quantum embeddings and quantum feature maps.

Comment: great, thank you for the references